# how to resize listview in android?

Tags: android

i have an android application which has a listview for listing 14 items inside it. i have coded as

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/my_list"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and my activity file is working as

```
ListView list;
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list_adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.my_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
my_list.setAdapter(list_adapter);
```

The code works properly. but i want to reduce the size of listview, so that i can list maximum items in the screen.

how can i do this? i had searched it. but didnt find any useful guidance.

Comment: sorry last line of code was list.setAdapter(list_adapter);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it dear...

Its simple...

I had just made my own layout in R/layout as mylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="7pt"    
              android:paddingTop="2dip" 
              android:paddingBottom="2dip"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"   
              android:gravity="center"/>
```

and then i changed my main.xml to show a listview. like,

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_list"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And atlast i have my actvty file like

```
    // all the stuff
    // i cant put my code here,na?:)
   //Its simple. just change layout to ours
    ListView list;
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list_adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.my_array, R.layout.mylist);
    my_list.setAdapter(list_adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either give fixed height to ListView instead of wrap_content or add other views in layout first then add ListView . remove layout_weight="1" .

Like a simlpe case is

```
<RelativieLayout>
<Button layout_alighParentBottom=true>
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ayot_above:btn
            android:id="@+id/my_list"/>
</relativeLayot>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to set width and height of listview. you can set it by right clicking on listview in xml and select set width / set height and set it, for ex. 20dp, 50 dp etc..
If you need to do something else, elaborate your question ..

Use relativelayout instead of linearlayout, that should be more simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an outer vertical `<LinearLayout>` and adding some more views. You do not need to make any code changes. This is the beauty of using layouts!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView .../>

    <TextView .../>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:clickable="true"
                  android:id="@+id/my_list"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For more info on layouts checkout the "[Hello, Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)" reference.